# HTML carousel using text over a static image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

(new to this)
I'm trying to get a static image with a carousel of different text going across the top. I've tried using the Bootstrap carousel HTML and removing sections (such as the multiple images), and using the "carousel-caption" class for my text, but that will take some styling to get it centered etc. This might be the best way, but if there is a simpler way, please let me know! (its in a jumbotron div as i was using a picture from my jumbotron section for ease)
TIA

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="testimonials">
      <div class="container">
          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
    <div class="carousel-text">
        <h3>Example headline</h3>
        <p>Example description</p>
      </div>
      <!-- <img src="img/lesson8-portfolioheroimage2.jpg" alt="..."> -->

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <!-- <img src="img/portfolioheroimage.jpg" alt="..."> -->
      <div class="carousel-text">
        <h3>Example head</h3>
        <p>Example description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <!-- <img src="img/portfolioheroimage3.jpg" alt="..."> -->
      <div class="carousel-text">
        <h3>Example headline</h3>
        <p>Example descri</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


      </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- jumbotron -->
```

Comment: What does this do or not do?

Comment: It gives a carousel of text over a static image, by just adding 1 image, (therefore no image carousel), but the  captions still revolve. I'm wondering if there was an easier way of doing it to prevent having to style all the carousel elements so much.... Would I be able to place an image in the div with the carousel overlaying it?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="carousel-text">
            <h3>Example headline</h3>
            <p>Example description</p>
          </div>
          <!-- <img src="img/lesson8-portfolioheroimage2.jpg" alt="..."> -->

        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <!-- <img src="img/portfolioheroimage.jpg" alt="..."> -->
          <div class="carousel-text">
            <h3>Example head</h3>
            <p>Example description</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <!-- <img src="img/portfolioheroimage3.jpg" alt="..."> -->
          <div class="carousel-text">
            <h3>Example headline</h3>
            <p>Example descri</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need something like this I guess?
You can beautify it as per your requirement.

Comment: Yeh that seems to work. My controls and indicators were all over the place, so this has sorted that. So i will just center the text using CSS...Thanks.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, please up vote the answer and mark it as correct please. Thank you.

Comment: Is that nearly the same as what I had? As it sort of does the same thing. I was still hoping for an easier way of doing it, but maybe that doesn't exist. Thanks for you answer though.